# can I create 2 sockets to the same server?

Tags: c, network-programming

Can I create 2 UDP sockets on the same client machine (but will be used in 2 different threads) to connect to a server? One thread sends datagrams to and the other receives datagrams from the server. Are these the correct steps:

1. create a sockaddr_in for the server's given address and UDP port.
2. create a socket and connect it to the server's sockaddr_in. This
   is the sending socket.
3. Create another socket, assign a port and
   sent the port number to the server.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use the same socket for sending and receiving?

Comment: Yes you can; but I'd first recommend reading Edward Lee on why threads are not good for this kind of an app.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's a requirement I have to follow.

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky: Thanks, can you send me the link.

Comment: @cody Maybe so, but it isn't a good requirement. It makes life harder for the server to receive from one port and respond to another: it also gums up the protocol with response ports in the request messages. Get this reviewed.